# Return all HTML elements inside a node

Tags: javascript

I have this code that get all elements inside body:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('body');
```

All I'm trying to do is store in a variable everything that exists inside the `body` element, for that i try to use `textContent`:

```
'tagName': elements[i].tagName, 
'textContentWithHtmlTags': elements[i].textContent,
```

The problem is that this command only returns me the texts, excluding the html tags.

In the case of the body of the page that I am analyzing, it has several elements like `header`, `footer`, `divs`, `links`... and within each of these elements, it has other elements and texts.

All that I would like to return, are the elements that exist below the body, in html format with their respective texts. For exemple:

```
<p>Hi World</p>
<div class="none"><a href="#">click me</a></div>
<strong>Yes, sir...</strong>
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HTMLElement.innerHTML` to get an element's content, HTML tags included.

And use `body *` selector to get all `<body>` children.

See:

```js
let data = [];

document.querySelectorAll('body *').forEach((element) => {
  data.push({
    tagName: element.tagName.toLowerCase(),
    content: element.innerHTML.trim()
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<p>Hi World</p>
<div class="none"><a href="#">click me</a></div>
<strong>Yes, sir...</strong>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few meanings to "*HTML elements inside a node*":

- elements that are immediate children of a node
- all elements inside a node at all depths

```
const node = document.querySelector('body')

const childrenElements = node.children

// const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('body *')
const allElements = node.querySelectorAll('*')
```

Next, convert list of nodes into list of useful data:

```
const data = Array.from(elements).map(el => {
  return {
    tagName: el.tagName,
    textContentWithHtmlTags: el.innerHTML,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Super easy way:
`var c = document.body.children;`
Now you have stored every node in the body in your "c" variable which basically is an array so you can access every node like you aways do with arrays.